# AJAX page fetch ignores javascript on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am calling an ajax script to fetch a content of a page and then replace the current contents with the fetched one. One problem I am facing is that there is a javascript on the fetched page which doesnt get rendered and is treated as text. How do I make sure that the javascript gets loaded?

Comment: Make sure that the contents of the code between `<script>` and `</script>` is VALID (ie doesn't throw errors). If this didn't solve your issue, show the relevant code and error messages.

Comment: Brb, let me get my glass bowl and so I can spot the errors in your code. Provide code please...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

write javascript(fetched page) code in main page.

for example:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "your fetched page url", 
    dataType: "html",
    type: 'POST',
    data: "your data", 
    success: function(data){ 
    $("#result").html(data); //call back div
        //put your javascript code from fetched page here               
    }
});
```

Comment: the fetchpage function is generic and is used in the entire site. and the script is not meant to be used everywhere.

Comment: so, try to make this part of script to be an function, add to be an `external js`. then call this `function` in `ajax success` part.